# 3rd table wont create

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have these queries

```
    QSqlQuery query;
  query.exec("Create table users (name varchar(20), type int)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO users values('Daihee',0)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO users values('Jessica',1)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO users values('Tony',1)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO users values('Yacine',0)");
  //PROJECTS
  query.exec("Create table projects (name varchar(20),owner varchar(20) ,teamSize int)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO projects values('P1','Daihee', 5)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO projects values('P2','Daihee', 5)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO projects values('P3','Daihee', 5)");

  query.exec("Create table projectStu (projectName varchar(30), stuName varchar(30)");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO projectStu values('P1','Jessica')");
  query.exec("INSERT INTO projectStu values('P2','Jessica')");
```

But the third table isn't being created, I'm also using SQLITE
Any tips could be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing paren `)` at the end of your third table definition.

Also have a look at the return value of `exec()` to see if something went wrong, and `lastError()` to know what it was.

Comment: you're a god, i've beenn staring at it for like 10 mins